# MVC 3 Razor: Country selection drop down list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to create a drop down list populated with countries for the user to pick from. So far all I have come across are long html lists that slow down my editor. I'm hoping there would be a quick way to do this in MVC 3 Razor.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be easy... Just like we did it in the old days :-)

Simply create a partial View with the country list as static HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674033/mvc-3-layout-page-razor-template-and-dropdownlist), but you'll need the country list, probably from a resource, instead of the years.