# Get dropdown list value in MVC3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, razor

Please help me to get the selected value of the dropdown list in the controller when i am clicking the submit button.

```
        My view is like
         @using (Html.BeginForm())
         {
            @foreach (var department in @Model)
            {
             items.Add(new SelectListItem
             {
                 Text = @department.DeptName,
                 Value = @department.DeptId.ToString()
             });                               

            }           
            @Html.DropDownList("deptID", items, "--Select One--", new { @style = width:160px" })                                               *              
            <input type="submit"   name="Filter" value="filter"  />
        }

    Please share if you are having any website link which explains about the dropdown list and its events in mvc3 Razor.
```

Thanks
San

Comment: do it the proper way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674033/mvc-3-layout-page-razor-template-and-dropdownlist/4678786#4678786

Comment: this has nothing to do with razor really

Comment: Thanks Bad Display Name i will do it :)

Answer (score 3):

MVC deals with the binding for you if you have a parameter with the same name

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string deptID) 
{
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: Thanks... int selectedValue= Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["deptID"]); is also works...

Comment: How do you call a controller function when a dropdown value is selected without using a submitt button?

Comment: @alice7 you need to use javascript (or a library like jQuery to make it simpler)