# How to use the mvc 3 dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello I'm new to mvc 3 and I need some pointers/help populating a dropdownlist. I have 3 classes which are my domain classes. Basically what I want to do is make a dropdownlist that will be populated with a specific members rented movies. What is the easiest way to do this? Is it to use the ViewBag or to make a ViewModel?

```
    public class Member
    {
        public virtual int MemberId { get; set; }
        public virtual long PersonalNr { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Rental> Rentals { get; set; }
    }
    public class Movie
    {
        public virtual int MovieId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsInStock { get; set; }

    }
   public class Rental
    {
        public virtual int RentalId { get; set; }
        public virtual int MovieId { get; set; }
        public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
        public virtual int MemberId { get; set; }
        public virtual Member Member { get; set; }

        public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime dueDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedRentalId,
    Model.Rentals
)
```

to know a little better on how to use it, including the select part, se [Darin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov)

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/6807331/28004