# JQuery MultiSelect to Update Entity Data Source

Tags: javascript, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using jquery.uix.multiselect.  Based on the selected options (Payment Categories) a gridview displays a list of payments.

At first I was using Static option values on the select box:

```
 <select  id="multiselectbox" multiple="true" size="4" 
    class="ui-multiselect" runat="server"> 
    <option value="11">Wine Expenses</option>
    <option value="12">Subs Old</option>
    <option value="13">Wine Receipts</option>
    <option value="14">Bank Fees</option>
    <option value="15">Bank Interest</option>
    <option value="16">Honour Boards</option>
 </select>
```

I was then getting a list of the selected category values in codebehind:

```
List<Int32> myIntList = new List<int>();;
    for (int i = 0; i < multiselectbox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (multiselectbox.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            CategoryIdList.Add(multiselectbox.Items[i].Value).Convert.ToInt32;
        }
    }
```

and finally using that to create a Where string for my entity data source:

```
if (myIntList.Count() != 0)
    {

        string concatenatedIds = string.Join(",", myIntList.ToArray());
        WhereClause = String.Format("{0} {1}{2}", "it.CategoryId IN {", concatenatedIds, "}");

    }
    EntityDataSource1Payments.WhereParameters.Clear();
    EntityDataSource1Payments.AutoGenerateWhereClause = false;
    EntityDataSource1Payments.Where = WhereString;
```

All was working well until I decided to populate the select box options from the database.

To do this, I ended up using a WebMethod, called it with AJAX and success, the multiselect was populated with value and name pairs from the database.  However, this caused my PaymentCategory filter to stop working.
I worked out the reason was that because the multiselect box was now being populated with javascript, the server side code didn't know what was in the select box and so multiselectbox.Items.Count was coming up with "0" and the for loop didn't do anything.

So then I decided I would have to use javascript to get the CategoryId values.  I was able to get the values in the multiselect quite easily:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function myButtonFunction() {


           var selectedlist = $(".ui-multiselect").val();
           alert(selectedlist);
           var finalObject = JSON.stringify(selectedlist);
           alert(finalObject);

           $.ajax({
               type: "post",
               contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               url: "displaypayments.aspx/GetWhereString",
               data: finalObject,
               datatype: "json",
               success: function () { 

                alert("seems to have gone okay"); },
               error: function () { alert("error"); }
           });
       }

</script>
```

however, despite having the correct list of CategoryId values, now I don't know what to do with them.

Solution 1) First I tried sending the list of Ids to the WebMethod above.  But I discovered a WebMethod has to be static, so I couldn't access the EntityDataSource in there either. Then I tried making a function in code behind to reset the Where String, but my WebMethod couldn't call the Function (instance - static issue again).  From further reading I worked out a Web Service might be the answer - but then I got stuck thinking that I would still have to use it to reset the EntityDataSource, or access the gridview to give it a new datasource, or....

Solution 2) Change the approach and now update the Entity Data Source with Javascript.  However, I cannot work out how to do this.  I don't know how to access the Where property of the Entity Data Source with JavaScript.  From reading up it seems to access controls with Java you need to access the ClientIdMode property so you know what to call it - but an EntityDataSource doesn't have a ClientIdMode....

Solution 3) I also thought about going back to the way I populate the Options, and thought I could do this in code behind - but it seems there's no ASP select Box, it's only HTML, so if I want to use the lovely jquery-uix-multiselect I have to populate it with javascript, no???

So my question is mostly about my approach. I've got the list of Ids, I've got a function that creates a nice whereclause filter that works, but I can't get the two things together.  I'm happy to go back a couple of steps and change the way I've done anything - I'm sure there's something very silly about the way I'm approaching this puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so in the end the answer was to change my approach to the way I populated the select box.

Instead of using jquery to populate the select box I populated it in code behind following the example from https://stackoverflow.com/users/502950/mikrodel

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14892701/2691962

Thankyou mikrodel.  I would vote you up but I don't have the reputation yet :)