# How to set default value for ASP.NET MVC DropDownList from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am new in mvc. so i populate dropdown this way

```
public ActionResult New()
{
    var countryQuery = (from c in db.Customers
                        orderby c.Country ascending
                        select c.Country).Distinct();
    List<SelectListItem> countryList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    string defaultCountry = "USA";
    foreach(var item in countryQuery)
    {
        countryList.Add(new SelectListItem() {
                        Text = item, 
                        Value = item, 
                        Selected=(item == defaultCountry ? true : false) });
    }
    ViewBag.Country = countryList;
    ViewBag.Country = "UK";
    return View();       
}

@Html.DropDownList("Country", ViewBag.Countries as List<SelectListItem>)
```

i like to know how can i populate dropdown from model and also set default value. any sample code will be great help. thanks

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("Country", ViewBag.Country as List<SelectListItem>, "DefaultValueHere")

Comment: you should use Model instead of ViewBag. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807256/dropdownlist-set-selected-value-in-mvc3-razor

Comment: @DanielMelo: actually, that parameter determines the name that should be shown for the "empty" option, *not* a default value.

Comment: Judging by the `@Html...` snippet, `ViewBag.Country = countryList;` should read `ViewBag.Countries = "UK";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well this is not a great way to do this.

Create a ViewModel that will hold everything you want to be rendered at the view.

```
public class MyViewModel{

  public List<SelectListItem> CountryList {get; set}
  public string Country {get; set}

  public MyViewModel(){
      CountryList = new List<SelectListItem>();
      Country = "USA"; //default values go here
}
```

Fill it with the data you need.

```
public ActionResult New()
{
    var countryQuery = (from c in db.Customers
                        orderby c.Country ascending
                        select c.Country).Distinct();
    MyViewModel myViewModel = new MyViewModel ();

    foreach(var item in countryQuery)
    {
        myViewModel.CountryList.Add(new SelectListItem() {
                        Text = item, 
                        Value = item
                        });
    }
    myViewModel.Country = "UK";



    //Pass it to the view using the `ActionResult`
    return ActionResult( myViewModel);
}
```

At the view, declare that this view is expecting a Model with type MyViewModel using the following line at the top of the file

```
@model namespace.MyViewModel
```

And at anytime you may use the Model as you please

```
@Html.DropDownList("Country", Model.CountryList, Model.Country)
```

Comment: what is this line Selected=(item == defaultCountry ? true : false) }); where is defaultCountry ?? it is not there in code.

Answer (score 3):

You can't set the default value using `Html.DropDownList`, if you want to have a default value, the property itself should have a default value.

```
private string country;
public string Country
{
    get { return country ?? "UK"; }
    set { country = value; }
}
```

Then, when the drop down list renders, as long as "UK" is actually a value for one of the options, it will be automatically set to that.

Answer (score 0):

If the `DropDownList` is filled in the controller and sent to the view via `ViewBag`, you can do:

```
ViewBag.MyName = new SelectList(DbContextname.Tablename, "Field_ID", "Description",idtobepresented);
```