# DropDownListFor Default Item with value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have a `@Html.DropdownlistFor` dropdownlist. I need to add default value to it. Here I give that dropdown default name as a cash I need to give it an option value here.

Name : CASH
Value : -1

Here is my Code

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customer_Supplier_CustomerSupplierId, (SelectList)ViewBag.ListOfCustomers, "CASH", new { placeholder = "CustomerName", id = "CustomerName", @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Set the default value in your constructor for the model

Answer (score 1):

As answered here :- [How to set default value for ASP.NET MVC DropDownList from model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991387/how-to-set-default-value-for-asp-net-mvc-dropdownlist-from-model)

> You can't set the default value using Html.DropDownList, if you want
>   to have a default value, the property itself should have a default
>   value.

```
 private string country; 
 public string Country
 {
  get { return country ?? "UK"; }
  set { country = value; } 
 }
```

> Then, when the drop down list renders, as long as "UK" is actually a
>   value for one of the options, it will be automatically set to that.

Comment: But in case you get the data from database and default values come from database, how you can achieve this?