# DropDownListFor is not showing selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC page on .NET 4.5.

This is my code - model classes:

```
public class UserDetail
{
    public Int64 UserID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string LoginID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; } = true;
    public DateTime LastLoginTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    // Columns for Mapping
    [Range(1,int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Select a Valid Group Value")]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Select a Valid Role Value")]
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}

public class UserViewModel
{
    public UserDetail User { get; set; } = new UserDetail();
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Groups { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model MyApp.Models.UserViewModel
<label for="ddl_role" class="font-weight-bold">Select Role</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.User.RoleID, Model.Roles, "Choose...", new { id = "ddl_role", @class = "form-control form-control-sm" })
```

Controller Action Method

```
public ActionResult SomeName()
{
    var viewmodel = new UserViewModel();
    viewmodel.Groups = Helper.GetSelectListItems(nameof(viewmodel.Groups));
    viewmodel.Roles = Helper.GetSelectListItems(nameof(viewmodel.Roles));
    viewmodel.User = Helper.GetData();

    return View(viewmodel);
}
```

`viewmodel.User = Helper.GetData()` extracts the data for `UserDetail` object and `viewmodel.Groups`, `viewmodel.Roles` both are `IEnumerable` of `SelectListItem`, they contain Text and Value fields.

But when I load the view, the dropdown always shows 'Choose...' as selected value, even though `Model.User.RoleID` is bound for reflecting the data and `SelectList` is also in place, but it does not show the selected value which is set through `Model.User.RoleID`

Any hint what I might be missing here?

Comment: @Jackdaw , yes I debugged and everything is correct , For example if value is set as 3 by model than in select list also contain a item with Value as 3

Comment: Strange, your code is working for me. Try to change the `RoleID` type to string, But actually it's working for me with `int` too.

Comment: @Jackdaw , Solution from Amit Mohanty worked, but is not that part handled automatically by framework ? Need some suggestion here coz even on MSDN this is not available

Comment: Very old post how to do this in elegant way: [How to set default value for ASP.NET MVC DropDownList from model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22991387/6630084)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the selected value based on `User.RoleID`.

```
viewmodel.Roles = Helper.GetSelectListItems(nameof(viewmodel.Roles));
viewmodel.Roles = viewmodel.Roles.Select(item => 
{
    item.Selected = (item.Value == viewmodel.User.RoleID.ToString());
    return item;
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm , But does not model binding does this task ??, Why we have to set this explicitly