# Set Selected value is dropdownList in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I have passed list items as select list in view from controller .

other data are retrieved from database

```
  var pairList = new List<KeyValuePair<String, Int32>>();
        var pair = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Daily", 0);
        pairList.Add(pair);
        pair = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Weekly", 7);
        pairList.Add(pair);
        //pair = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Bi-Weekly", 14);
        //pairList.Add(pair);
        pair = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Monthly", 30);
        pairList.Add(pair);

        ViewBag.frequency = new SelectList(pairList, "Value", "Key", null);
```

and it view i was to display selected value while page loads .

by some working I get the selected value like 7 or 30 etc from other functional which is also dynamic

```
 <td id="testa">                                          
  @Html.DropDownList("testddl", ViewBag.frequency as SelectList)
</td>
```

How can I set selected value .

Thnaks 
Binaya

Comment: possible duplicate of [dropdownlist set selected value in MVC3 Razor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807256/dropdownlist-set-selected-value-in-mvc3-razor)

Comment: Similar but i want to achieve using viewbag as select list not pass as model with selected option ?

Comment: Are you able to provide a reason for your approach? Using the `ViewBag` makes things more difficult and complex.