# How to show selected value in DropDownList of MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

Below is my DropDownList in view

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-4">                           
 @Html.DropDownList("Status",new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem{ Text="Active", Value = "Active" },new SelectListItem{ Text="InActive", Value = "InActive" }}, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

From DB value is coming either as "Active" or "Inactive" and dropdown has already these two value. And from my DB i'm assigning value in `ViewBag.IsStatus`.
Now suppose my value is coming "InAactive" from DB then how to assign this as Selected value in Dropdown rather than to show First dropdown by default as selected.

Comment: The values of your options are `0` and `1` (not `"Active"` and `"Inactive"`) so if the value of property `Status` is `1`, then the second option will be selected.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6807331/3074022

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok i have changed my value same as that of Text. but still not got my desired result.

Comment: Do you have a model property named `Status`? You should always be using the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods (`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Status, .....)`)

Comment: @Sousuke i'm binding my dropdown in View side which are having only two options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use `DropDownListFor` if you  using MVC. But for your case just create `SelectList` and pass it to `DropDownList`. `SelectList` contructor has overload for selected value:

```
@{ //theese lines actually should be in controller.
 var list = new List<SelectListItem> 
             { 
             new SelectListItem 
                   { 
                       Text="Active", 
                       Value = "0" 
                   }
             ,new SelectListItem
                   { 
                       Text="InActive", 
                       Value = "1" 
                    }
             }
}

//thats your code
<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-4">                           
   @Html.DropDownList("Status",new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text", ViewBag.IsStatus), new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Comment: i have shifted ' var list=' in my controller then how i will access that list in my view inside `SelectList`

Comment: @Steve but you ctreate this list with the code above?

Comment: @Steve in your controller you should use `ViewData.Model` to store this. And then use Model to get this value. **Or** you can just use `ViewBag.list` and then access to this data with `ViewBag.list` on View

Comment: `public ActionResult GetEditRecord(long Id)
  {
     using (StoreProcedureContext sc = new StoreProcedureContext())
      {
         var list = new List<SelectListItem> 
       { 
         new SelectListItem 
        { 
          Text="Active", 
           Value = "0" 
          }
             ,new SelectListItem
          { 
         Text="InActive", 
          Value = "1" 
           }                    
           };
          ViewBag.List = list;
          var cmd = sc.EditUsers(Id);
          ViewBag.IsDeleted = cmd.ToList()[0].IsDeleted;
          return View(cmd);
         }
        }`

Comment: and my view
`@Html.DropDownList("Status", new SelectList(ViewBag.List, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" })`
please tell me where i'm doing wrong. I want that `ViewBag.IsDeleted` value to selected by default.

Comment: @Steve and where is `ViewBag.IsDeleted` in your `DropDownList` helper? =) i mean `@Html.DropDownList("Status", new SelectList(ViewBag.List, "Value", "Text", ViewBag.IsDeleted), new { @class = "form-control" })`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a model with Status property then simply assign this the value to the property (for example in controller):

Model

```
public class Model
{

    public string Status {get;set;}
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    //the value has to correspond to the Value property of SelectListItems
    //that you use when you create dropdown
    //so if you have new SelectListItem{ Text="Active", Value = "Active" }
    //then the value of Status property should be 'Active' and not a 0
    var model = new Model{Status = "Active"}

    return this.View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@model Model


@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Status,new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem{ Text="Active", Value = "Active" },new SelectListItem{ Text="InActive", Value = "InActive" }}, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FirstOrDefault().IsDelete, new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "Active", Value = "false" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "InActive", Value = "true" } }, new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: isDelete is my bool property but i'm not able to fetch same as you said for selected value

Comment: that is to show column name. columns name were not coming but after writing `FirstOrDefault` it was showing columns name for the model

Comment: @Steve It's actually looks like your model is a collection(or a list) and not a single object...

Comment: please show the vIew and corresponding controller action code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109692/discussion-between-alex-art-and-steve).