# Remember selected option after post

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

i have this code

```html
<select name="item.location" class="selectpicker">
    
    @foreach (var x in JournalConnector.GetAllLocations())
    {
        <option id="line" value="@x">@x</option>

    }
</select>
```

which gets the locations that are in the database.

after i post my form i want it to remember the selected option and start the page on it again.

the rest of the code on the page is here: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ej9y0f5q/)

i have tried using localstorage and session storage, but neither saves the value i need to save (which would be @x)

Comment: Can't you just bring back the value from database and match in your HTML rather than saving it in local or session storage?

Comment: In your function where form procession is done, return the selected value to the view and by using that value make drop down selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select name="item.location" class="selectpicker">

    @foreach (var x in JournalConnector.GetAllLocations())
    {           
       @if(ViewBag.SelectedID ==x.id ){
            <option id="line" selected="selected" value="@x">@x</option>
        }
        else{
            <option id="line" value="@x">@x</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

this is not the exact code, but this is the idea

in the controller

save the posted id to a viewbag

```
ViewBag.SelectedID = ID;
```

Comment: This solution works but I'd advise against using ViewBag as it is a dynamic object and it can get quite messy.
Also you could make use of the HTML Helper for DropDownLists which would simplify you code for you.
Have a look at this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807256/dropdownlist-set-selected-value-in-mvc3-razor

Comment: thank you for the solution, i used yours with some modifications - and now its working.