# How to set the value of a dropdownlist in mvc without allowing the user to change it

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i'm very new to MVC and I want to know if this is possible. I want the JobID to be set to a value that i have in the **ViewBag**. I want to remove the **DropdownList** so that the value is automatically assigned without having the user to select the value from the List.
[Create Task Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1fnT.png)

[Create Task View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT95E.png)

[Website View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1Fhs.png)

If you look at image 3. I want to remove this dropdownlist and have that value already assigned. Any help will be appreciated thank you.

Comment: You can set value of JObID in viewbag like **`ViewBag.JobID=Model.JobID`** thats it.

Answer (score -1):

Disable the dropdownlist for user as below,

```
Html.DropDownList("JobID", Model.JobID, new {@class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you know how to set the JobID = to the viewbag.Job?

Comment: I guess following link can help you with that, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807256/dropdownlist-set-selected-value-in-mvc3-razor)