# Populating a dropdownlist from a value type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

This obviously is pretty basic question but I haven't found my way around this: I'm trying to create a dropdown list for an integer property of my Model, so I can populate the dropdown with a default list of values.

My controller looks like this:

```
ViewBag.MyListOfOptions = new SelectList(new int[] { 5, 15, 25, 50 });
```

And my view looks like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyIntField, new SelectList(ViewBag.MyListOfOptions , [dataValueField], [dataTextField]))
```

Most examples I've found **dataValueField** and **dataTextField** are the properties that should be used in creating the dropdown, but I haven't found a way on how to use DropDownListFor with value types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you created the `SelectList` from `MyListOfOptions` which is already a `SelectList` you can use "Text" and "Value"

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyIntField, 
    new SelectList(ViewBag.MyListOfOptions , "Value", "Text"))
```

But you don't need to wrap again an SelectList, so this will also work:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyIntField,
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.MyListOfOptions)
```

Comment: Perfect! I imagined that would be something as simple as that

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to get around this is to take this approach using a `ViewModel`:

[dropdownlist set selected value in MVC3 Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6807331/114029)

[MVC 3 Layout Page, Razor Template, and DropdownList](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4678786/114029)