# How to create aDropDown list list from IDictionary<string, string> using Razor in ASp.Net Mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How to create a DropDown list from IDictionary using Razor in ASp.Net Mvc3?? I=m trying the following code wit no success.

```
 public IDictionary<string, string> CandidatesList = new Dictionary<string, string>();


    Html.DropDownListFor(modal => modal.CandidatesList, new SelectList(Model.CandidatesList, "Value", "Key"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bind the dropdown to the same property as the second argument. You must bind it to a primitive type property on your model:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.SelectedCandidateKey, 
    new SelectList(Model.CandidatesList, "Value", "Key")
)
```

where `SelectedCandidateKey` must be a string property on your view model which will hold the selected item key.

Think of it this way: when you need a dropdownlist in ASP.NET MVC you have to declare 2 properties on your view model:

1. a primitive type property that will hold the selected value
2. an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property that will hold all the available values

Comment: May I ask yo why DropDownListFor is not available on IDictionary? thanks

Comment: What do you mean by not available? Are you asking why you cannot bind a DropDownListFor to a complex type as first argument? That's because it wouldn't make sense. In HTML only the selected value is sent to the server when you submit a form containing a `<select>` element - it's just how HTML works.

Comment: Thanks Darin for clarification :-)

Comment: this answer help me to understand you point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674033/mvc-3-layout-page-razor-template-and-dropdownlist