# JQuery Ajax Post Not Working As Expected

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-post

I'm building an **MVC 5** web application which has a drop down list contained within the layout template. I have followed this answer on **stackoverflow** and it works well [MVC 3 Layout Page, Razor Template, and DropdownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674033/mvc-3-layout-page-razor-template-and-dropdownlist)

What I need is for the User to select an item (persons name) from the drop down list, a JQuery call to be made which then passes the selected drop down list ID into a method within a Controller.

I have a drop down list declared like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedUserID, Model.UserList, "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

When an item is selected, the following JQuery code is called

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#SelectedUserID").change(ChangeEventOfDDL);

function ChangeEventOfDDL() {

    alert("test val" + $(this).val());

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Dashboard/Index/' + $(this).val(),
        data: { id: $(this).val() },
        dataType: "json",
        error: function () {
            alert("An error occurred.");
        },
        success: function (data) {

        }

    });
}

});
```

This then passes the selected ID to the Index method in my Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        DashboardViewModel model = new DashboardViewModel();

        if(id == null || id == 0)
        {
            User user = _userService.GetUserByID(Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.GetUserId()));
            model.SelectedUser = user;
        }
        else
        {
            model.SelectedUser = _userService.GetUserByID(id.Value);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

This all seems to work fine. When I debug through my code I can see the selected Drop Down List ID being passed through the code as expected all the way to the Index method in my Controller. The problem is, when I complete stepping through the code and return to the UI, a JQuery error occurs with a prompt stating "An error occurred.". This is the default error message I have set in my JQuery function.

Because this error occurs my code doesn't work properly.

I have no idea why this is happening, can anyone please help?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Before using the Ajax call inside of the ChangeEventOfDLL Function I had used the following code, however, it never actually hit the Index method in the Dashboard.

```
$.post('@Url.Action("Dashboard", "Index")', { id: $(this).val() }, function (result) {
});
```

**UPDATE**

I change my JQuery to this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#SelectedUserID").change(ChangeEventOfDDL);

function ChangeEventOfDDL() {

    alert("test val" + $(this).val());

    $.post('@Url.Action("Index", "Dashboard")', { id: $(this).val() }, function (result) {
    });
}

});
```

But still the Index method does not get called in the Controller.

Next I updated the JQuery code to this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#SelectedUserID").change(ChangeEventOfDDL);

function ChangeEventOfDDL() {

    alert("test val" + $(this).val());

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Index","Dashboard")',
        data: { id: $(this).val() },
        error: function () {
            alert("An error occurred.");
        },
        success: function (data) {

        }

    });

}

});
```

But still the Index method is not called in the Controller and I still get the Error Prompt.

Comment: why do you have a `dataType:json` ? I don't see any json returned from your Action ? And why does your Action return a View ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Apologies, please see my update. I copied in the Ajax code from a previous app and it actually hit Index method in my Controller, whereas my previous code (see update) didn't. Can you help? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is not the "go to the controller action", the problem is why do you think that your method is returning json, and why do you return a View ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I know my method isn't returning Json, it was a mistake as stated in previous comment, please see update. Also, I need to return a View, what is wrong with this?

Comment: @tgriffiths $(this) will be undefined inside ajax call do the way i did in updated answer

Comment: also change the type to 'Get'

Comment: or add [HttpPost] on your action

Comment: what do you want to return by the ajax call,In your controller action you are returning a View but in your ajax call you set dataType:"json",this is a conflict

Comment: if you want to return a view then don't set dataType:"json", because then your ajax call expect to return a json, though you are actually returning html from you controller action

Comment: what you want to return from your action?

Comment: @janina A View. I have updated my code, please see updated question. I am no longer returning Json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are passing `datatype:json`while you are returning view from action, and another mistake is you are passing id in data attribute as well and in url as well, this is also wrong:
this should be:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Dashboard/Index/' + $(this).val(),
    data: { id: $(this).val() },
    dataType: "json",
    error: function () {
        alert("An error occurred.");
    },
    success: function (data) {

    }

});
```

like this:

```
var id = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("Index","Dashboard")',
    data: { id: id  },
    error: function () {
        alert("An error occurred.");
    },
    success: function (data) {

    }

});
```

**Note:** Always use **Url.Action** helper you create the action url so that it will not create issues on live deployment.

if you want to return only object not view then do like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        DashboardViewModel model = new DashboardViewModel();

        if(id == null || id == 0)
        {
            User user = _userService.GetUserByID(Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.GetUserId()));
            model.SelectedUser = user;
        }
        else
        {
            model.SelectedUser = _userService.GetUserByID(id.Value);
        }

        return JsonResult(model,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and then you have to put **dataType:'json'** in the ajax call.

**Update:**

Make ddl event like this:

```
$("#SelectedUserID").change(function(){

ChangeEventOfDDL($(this).val());

});
```

your function:

```
function ChangeEventOfDDL(id)
{
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Index","Dashboard")',
        data: { id: id  },
        error: function () {
            alert("An error occurred.");
        },
        success: function (data) {

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: That's true you passing the ID through the URL as well. Don't do that.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I made your changes to my Ajax call (excluding the dataType: json)..however, my Index method does not get called when I select an item from the drop down list? Any ideas?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Thanks, I tried your changes but still it doesn't work. I keep getting the Erro Prompt - "An error occurred."

Comment: what is the error,see in the ajax, call $(this) will be undefined inside ajax call and also set ajax call type 'GET' as your action is get not post

Answer (score 1):

Then Remove `dataType:"json"` from you ajax set up

And in your action use `return PartialView("ViewName",model)` instead of `return View("ViewName",model)`

In case you return partial view else return view()

Comment: because you are not returning any json, this must work

Answer (score 0):

It is going in to the error function because you have specified the datatype as JSON
hence `dataType: 'json'` But you are not returning JSON back to the function you are returning a view and thats why the error is thrown. Change your Action Result to a Json result and do this.

```
public JsonResult(int? id)
{
         // blah blah blah
       return Json(model.SelectedUser, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

*> only write in your Mvc controller funtion this line

> Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = fals*

e;